# Can one prove that two Groups are not homomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Sorry if I sound too ignorant, I'm barely starting to study abstract algebra.

---

While learning about Group theory, I found a video that explains the concept of Group Homomorphisms.

If I understood correctly, it goes something like this: $G$ is a group with the operator $*$ and $H$ is a group with the operator $+$, a homomorphism between these two groups would be a function that maps two elements of $G$ into $H$ in the following way:

$f(x)+f(y)=f(x*y)$

---

It seems as a pretty simple definition, in fact, I wonder if one could just construct a function $g$ as a homomorphism of two groups, in other words, defining $g$ as some function such that $g(x)+g(y)=g(x*y)$. However, the lady ends the video saying that "some groups are so different from one another, there are no structural similarities at all", meaning -I think- that there exist pair of groups that are not homomorphic.

Is this the case? Or are all groups homomorphic? Whether they are or not, could someone provide a proof or explanation?

Any thoughts/ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: There is always the trivial homomorphism, mapping all elements onto the neutral element.

Comment: Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $H=\mathbb{Z}/3$. Then there is no non-trivial group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

Comment: What does "homomorphic" mean?

Comment: @leo: you should interpret her comment as Chan kifung indicates: although there is always the trivial morphism, non-trivial examples do not always exist. The trivial ones are not the most interesting.

Comment: If I understood Student correctly, there will always exist a function that maps all the element of $G$ onto the identity of the group $H$ and has the characteristic that $f(x)+f(y) = f(x*y)$...right?

Comment: @Derek Holt: I'm barely getting a grasp at the definitions, so I honestly don't know. In my question I use the word "homomoprhic" as if if there exist a homomorphism between two groups, then they are homomorphic. I recognize it might not be the correct way to use the word, if it even exist.

Comment: @leo: (1/2) it seems to me (forgive me if this is not the case) that you did not completely got the notion of 'homomorphism'. The homomorphism maps a single element of $G$ onto a single element of $H$: $f: G \to H$. However, we have the extra requirement that for two elements in $G$ it does not matter if we multiply them first and take the image of the product or if we first take the image of each element and multiply them afterwards (multiplying = apllying the appropriate group operator). If you wish, I can write a more detailled answer tomorrow (about the notion of homimorphism

Comment: @leo (2/2) since two nice examples are given about the non-existence of non-trivial homomorphism between certain groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, merely *having* a homomorphism between two groups $G, H$ is not useful. But nonetheless, we can sometimes reveal a lot about a group by looking at what kinds of homomorphisms come in and out of it. Others have already mentioned the matter of embeddings, i.e. when there's an injective homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$. This means that $G$ is in a way "part" of $H$, or more specifically there's a subgroup of $H$ isomorphic to $G$.

Another example of how group homomorphisms tell us things about the structure of a group involves an idea called quotient groups. The principle behind them is that I can take a group $G$ and then identify certain elements of $G$ with each other, and then establish an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G$ such that $G / \sim$ is a group after inheriting the group operation from $G$. We call these "quotient groups".

It's an elementary result that a group $G$ has a quotient group isomorphic to $H$ if and only if there's a surjective homomorphism $\psi : G \to H$. So in this way, we can use the homomorphisms in and out of $G$ to establish structural properties of $G$. There are many, many, many more examples of this in group theory, but these are some basic ones.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematicians typically don't use the word "homomorphic" that way, for the reason (as pointed out above) that for *any* two groups, $G,H$, the $0$-map (or *trivial map*):

$0:G \to H$ given by $0(g) = e_H$ for all $g \in G$ (map everything in $G$ to the group identity of $H$), always exists.

In any case, the existence, or non-existence, of a (non-trivial) homomorphism between two groups is a poor yardstick of similarity; for distinct primes $p, q$ there is no non-trivial group homomorphism $f: \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$, but very few mathmeticans would claim this groups are "dissimilar" (they are both simple cyclic groups).

It is (perhaps) more fruitful to think of a homomorphism $f: G \to f(G) \subseteq H$ as "preserving" partial information about $G$ "inside" of $H$. Some information about $G$ can be lost, as homomorphisms are not always one-to-one (when they *are* one-to-one, this is a highly desirable situation, as we have a "copy" of $G$ inside $H$, and $H$ may be "easier" to understand than $G$).

Groups *can* be very different from one another (as opposed to, say, finite-dimensional vector spaces over the reals, which are all rather alike). This is mostly because groups have *so few rules*, that some wildly disparate sets and operations can still qualify to be groups. Mathematicians have developed *classifications*, such as order, simplicity, etc. to help distinguish groups by *type*, and it turns out this is....complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way : If the groups $G,H$ have respective orders $|G|,|H|$ with $gcd(|G|,|H|)=1 $; WOLG$|G|<|H|$, then there  cannot be a non-trivial injective homomorphism , so that there is no "embedding" or copy of $G$ in $H$ : if they were, the image $h(G)$ of the supposed homomorphism $h$ would be a subgroup of $H$. But the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group, which is not possible if $|G|$ does not divide $|H|$.